# intercepting session set attribute call

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, web, replication

We have a third party Java web application which needs to run in a cluster (we need to replicate session across the cluster), session attributes within the application are not serializable and we do not are access to the source code, are their clean, non intrusive ways to intercept session.set attribute calls and change the objects before they are put in session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing `HttpSessionAttributeListener` is not a solution that is OK with you, there is the option of using a `ServletFilter`. Not sure is that is too intrusive for your requirements, though...

1. Activate this ServletFilter first in the chain
2. Wrap the `HTTPServletRequest` you're passing down the chain with your own implementation of `HttpServletRequestWrapper`,  overriding `getSession` by returning a decorator implementation of the original container created `Session` implementation
3. Your decorator is your gateway to intercepting the `setAttribute` methods.

Comment: I have had this playing in my head but holding out for a less intrusive solution, will give this a shot, will accept this answer if I do not get different perspective

Comment: Also, I was asking myself if there is a risk that somebody (most likely at the servlet container level) could access the session before you decorate it and even cache the original session object... Hopefully, although possible, there is little chance of something doing that.